# quiero juntar 2 graficos en la misma figura

Tags: python, matplotlib

tengo que hacer 2 tipos de rotaciones de figuras y que aparezcan en la misma pestaña y controladas por 3 'sliders' ( ejes Y,X,Y). Ya hice las 2 rotaciones por separado pero no puedo juntarlas, me salen 2 "pestañas" cada una con sus respectivos 'sliders'  por favor si alguien me puede explicar como hago para que me aparezcan en la misma pestaña

Comment: ¿y  dónde quedó el código?

Comment: no me deja ponerlo. Soy nuevo en la pagina y quise poner el codigo, me decia que era mas codigo que informacion asi que no lo puse

Comment: Bienvenido! Esa restricción es por que no conviene que publiques todo el código. Te recomiendo reducir tu código a un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y de paso leer más del centro de ayuda para conocer mejor el sitio.